# Passing Values of list of controls created by javascript from view to controller in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I am trying to learn MVC3 by developing a online Education system.
I am facing problem of passing value of textboxes and dropdown which are created by javascript from view to controller using view model. I have a scenario in which student add its list of current qualifications.
[image]

In the above image I have tried to explain my problem.

At first only one row of education will view in view Page. When student click on Add button a new row will be added below it and so on.

I have created a StudentEducation ViewModel. I have also studied several questions on stack overflow similar like this. In all I have found that a generic list property is created and create controls in view by looping it. But my problem is at first there is not object in list i.e. I cannot set number of qualification student will add.

So Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a ViewModel named `StudentEducation`.

In your post Action, you need a `List<StudentEducation>` like

```
[HttpPost]
public Action MyAction(List<StudentEducation> students)
{
    // ...
}
```

You also need a get Action to fetch the View. At first it will be empty and will not contain any record

```
public Action MyAction()
{
   // here, initialize your 
   // List<StudentEducation> vm = new List<StudentEducation>();
   // and send it to view like
   return View(vm);
}
```

You also need a strongly typed view. In you view, you need to iterate your model and create list items like

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentEducation>

for (var i = 0; i < @Model.count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].PropertyName)
}
```

Here is the interesting thing. The list will bind properly if your generated HTML markup is like

```
<input type="text" value="something" name="[1].PropertyName" />
```

Here `name="[1].PropertyName"` is the most important thing. If you create your list HTML with names in this pattern then you will get a filled `List<Studenteducatio>` upon form submission

Answer (score 0):

You basicly need to model-bind to a list. Each new row you add into your table via JavaScript will have to have correct Id-s set to the html inputs.

I faced the same problem some time a go and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) article by Phil Haack helped me to solve the problem.

I ended up generating a new row (although in my case it was a whole subform that could be entered multiple times) template to use when user pressed the "Add" button. I also implemented a JavaScript helper function that calculated the correct sequence number of the row to be inserted. I did not need to change anything in the controllers, model-binding just worked.

Comment: Thanks. After reading Phil Hacck article I have successfully solved my problem. I have also tried by creating a partial view. But no luck. I have a student view model in which there is a property StudentEducationList of generic type. I am looping it into view and call html.partial with partial view name and object model with index. It created desired controls but as I am posting view with student view model it does not passes values of studenteducation viewmodel of which there is a property in student view model of list type. Can you please sent me the code of your partial view implementation.